# Create a new list for every element of another list with for loops

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, nested-loops

I have a nested list (where every subelement is a pdfminer.LTPage) and I'd want to get a list for every element of the initial nested list.

This below is my code so far

```py
def my_fun(nested_in):
    List_out = []
    List_out.append([x for n in range(len(nested_in))
                     for item in nested_in[n]
                     for x in item
                     if isinstance(x,pdfminer.layout.LTTextBoxHorizontal)])

    return List_out
```

The output I get is a nested list with only one element that contains as a subelement the totality of the wanted element, but what I expected was a nested list where each item included all LTTextBoxHorizontal of one LTPage.

Answer (score 1):

Your description is a little ambiguous. Maybe you can try:

```py
def my_fun(nested_in):
    List_out = []
    for ele in nested_in:
        List_out.append([x for item in ele
                         for x in item
                         if isinstance(x,pdfminer.layout.LTTextBoxHorizontal)])

    return List_out
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, I also tried with an empty list inside the first for loop and that worked out!